# How can I specify the record delimiter to be used in SQLite's output?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using the following command to output the result of an SQL query to a text file:

```
$sqlite3 my_db.sqlite "SELECT text FROM message;" > out.txt
```

This gives me output like this:

```
text for entry 1
text for entry 2
```

Unfortunately, this breaks down when the text contains a newline:

```
text for entry 1
text for 
entry 2
```

How can I specify an output delimiter (which I know doesn't exist in the text) for SQLite to use when outputting the data so I can more easily parse the result? E.g.:

```
text for entry 1
=%=
text for 
entry 2
=%=
text for entry 3
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In order to seperate columns, you would have to work with group_concat and a seperator.

Query evolution:

```
SELECT text FROM messages;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(text, "=%=") FROM messages;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(text, "\r\n=%=\r\n") FROM messages;

// to get rid of the concat comma, use replace OR change seperator
SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(text, "\r\n=%="), ',', '\r\n') FROM messages;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cdbb/4)**

Alternative: Sqlite to CSV export (with custom seperator), then work with that.

Comment: In more recent versions of Sqlite (at least since v3.31.1, included in Ubuntu 20.04), the way to handle this is with the `.separator` special command or the `-newline` command-line option ([doc](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#command_line_options)).

Answer (score 8):

Try [-separator option](http://www.sqlite.org/sessions/sqlite.html) for this.

```
$sqlite3 -separator '=%=' my_db.sqlite "SELECT text FROM message;" > out.txt
```

**Update 1**

I quess this is because of '-list' default option. In order to turn this option off you need to change current mode.

This is a list of modes

```
.mode MODE ?TABLE?     Set output mode where MODE is one of:
                            csv      Comma-separated values
                            column   Left-aligned columns.  (See .width)
                            html     HTML <table> code
                            insert   SQL insert statements for TABLE
                            line     One value per line
                            list     Values delimited by .separator string
                            tabs     Tab-separated values
                            tcl      TCL list elements


 -list  Query results will  be  displayed  with  the  separator  (|,  by
        default) character between each field value.  The default.

 -separator separator
        Set output field separator.  Default is '|'.
```

Found this info [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/sqlite3.1.html)

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to set the separator for columns, not records. So if I were to 'SELECT text,guid FROM message', '=%=' would separate the id and the text, but the records themselves are still separated by a newline. (I'm using SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-07-17 17:46:21.)

Comment: The `-separator` option controls the column separator, but for records the option is `-newline` (with the default of "\n").

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and there is a simpler solution.  I found this at https://sqlite.org/cli.html :

> .separator COL ?ROW?     Change the column and row separators

For example:

```
    sqlite> .separator | ,
    sqlite> select * from example_table;

1|3,1|4,1|15,1|21,1|33,2|13,2|16,2|32,
```

Or with no column separator:

```
    sqlite> .separator '' ,
    sqlite> select * from example_table;

13,14,115,121,133,213,216,232,
```

Or, to answer the specific question posed above, this is all that is needed:

```
    sqlite> .separator '' \r\n=%=\r\n
    sqlite> select * from message;

text for entry 1
=%=
text for
entry 2
=%=
text for entry 3
=%=
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `.separator COL [ROW]` special command when in the interactive prompt, as answered by @dadosalado in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60417188/552683, or the `-newline SEP` command-line option. ([doc](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#command_line_options))